# What does a try catch change in a while statement that uses @@ROWCOUNT?

Tags: t-sql

I want to add a try catch to a while loop. The loop used while on @@ROWCOUNT > 0. In the while I have an update top (100) statement that works well without a try catch around it. When I add the try, the while ends in the first loop. What impact does the try have on @@ROWCOUNT that makes the while loop end even tough the update touched 100 records?

```
--do we have anything to process?
select top 1 * from SomeTable where processedFlag is null

WHILE(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN

  begin try
    -- here I have an udpate top (100) statement that processes records with null flag in small batches
  end try
  begin catch
    -- update @@ROWCOUNT so the while continues?
    select top 1 * from SomeTable where processedFlag is null 
  end catch
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it because of

> Statements such as USE, SET , DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR,
>   BEGIN TRANSACTION or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0.

May be `END TRY` is among them, but `MSDN` doesn't list all possible statements.

This will fix the problem:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE processedFlag IS NULL

WHILE(@i > 0)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
      UPDATE...
      SET @i = @@ROWCOUNT    
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
      SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE processedFlag IS NULL
  END CATCH
END
```

Comment: @@Rowcount falls out of scope in the catch I believe which is why this work around works.